# google Timeline Chart json data

Tags: json, google-visualization

I am creating a Google Timeline Chart with JSON data from a Sheet. I have a hardcoded the timeline and parsed my json data, but I am having trouble combining the 2.

```
The hardcoded rows where I'd like to pull in the dynamic json data is this:
dataTable.addRows([   
  [ 'Project Name', null, '<div class="ggl-tooltip">Dynamic Task</div>', new Date(2001, 6, 14), new Date(2001, 6, 17) ]   
 ]);

My json data looks like this:
{cols: Array(4), rows: Array(3)}
cols: Array(4)
0: {id: "B", label: "Milestone", type: "number", pattern: "General"}
1: {id: "D", label: "Task", type: "string"}
2: {id: "F", label: "Start Date", type: "date", pattern: "M/D/YYYY"}
3: {id: "G", label: "End Date", type: "date", pattern: "M/D/YYYY"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
rows: Array(3)
0:
c: Array(4)
0: {v: 1, f: "1"}
1: {v: "Design Registration Portal, Invitation, Confirmati…ecruitment Dashboard with Placeholder information"}
2: {v: "Date(2021, 1, 25)", f: "2/25/2021"}
3: {v: "Date(2021, 2, 4)", f: "3/4/2021"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
1: {c: Array(4)}
2: {c: Array(4)}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: are you trying to draw the chart with the data from the query / json? if so, you don't need to add any rows, or do anything, they are already included. draw the chart with the data from the response...

Comment: Yes and no. There are some custom rows I added to the top of the chart and html I'd like to keep around the tooltip text. I though if I could pull the parsed json data into the DrawChart function I could add a dataTable.addRows line for each row in the json, pulling in the dynamic data that way.